# Centos7 with directadmin - phpmyadmin blank page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos7, directadmin

I have some trouble with my PHPMyAdmin on dedicated server.
Directadmin was installed with system CentOS7 by soyoustart.com

Here is line with phpmyadmin error line from apatche error logs:

```
[Tue Jun 28 10:22:51.938070 2016] [:error] [pid 30558] [client 88.199.88.94:50300] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:2222/CMD_DB?domain=xxxxxxx.com
```

Could someone tell me how to reinstall PHPMyAdmin on CentoOS 7 or how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the permissions on /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/ and /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/index.php -- are they readable by the webserver process? Can you access it directly as http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/index.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Set session.save_path to /tmp in your php.ini file and restart httpd services to fix this issues.